# Explicitly typing an object with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm working on converting my little library from JavaScript to TypeScript, and I have a function there

```
function create(declarations: Declarations) {
```

Now the declaration is an object the keys of which can be of 2 types:

- If the keys are one of those strings: `onMemeber` / `onCollection`, then the value should be a number
- For any other string keys the value should be a string

Is that possible to enforce with TypeScript? How should I define my `Declarations` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concrete type in TypeScript that represents your `Declarations` shape.

I'd call the general idea a "default property" type.  (GitHub issue asking for this is [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867)) You want specific properties to be of one type, and then any others to "default" to some other incompatible type.  It's like an  [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) without the constraint that all properties must be assignable to it.

( Just to be clear, an index signature cannot be used:

```
type BadDeclarations = {
    onMember: number, // error! number not assignable to string
    onCollection: number, // error! number not assignable to string
    [k: string]: string
};
```

The index signature `[k: string]: string` means *every* property must be assignable to `string`, even `onMember` and `onCollection`.  To make an index signature that actually works, you'd need to widen the property type from `string` to `string | number`, which probably doesn't work for you. )

There were some [pull requests that would have made this possible](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317#issuecomment-487643147), but it doesn't look like they are going to be part of the language any time soon.

Often in TypeScript if there's no concrete type that works you can use a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) in some way.  Here's how I'd make `Declarations` generic:

```
type Declarations<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends 'onMember' | 'onCollection' ? number : string
};
```

And here's the signature for `create()`L

```
function create<T extends Declarations<T>>(declarations: T) {
}
```

You can see that the `declarations` parameter is of type `T`, which is constrained to `Declarations<T>`.  This self-referential constraint ensures that for every property `K` of `declarations`, it will be of type `K extends 'onMember' | 'onCollection' ? number : string`, a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) that is a fairly straightforward translation of your desired shape.

Let's see if it works:

```
create({
    onCollection: 1,
    onMember: 2,
    randomOtherThing: "hey"
}); // okay

create({
    onCollection: "oops", // error, string is not assignable to number
    onMember: 2,
    otherKey: "hey",
    somethingBad: 123, // error! number is not assignable to string
})
```

That looks reasonable to me.

---

Of course, using a generic type isn't without some annoyances; suddenly every value or function that you wanted to use `Declarations` with will need to be generic now.  So you can't do `const foo: Declarations = {...}`.  You'd need `const foo: Declarations<{onCollection: number, foo: string}> = {onCollection: 1, foo: ""}` instead.  That's obnoxious enough that you'd likely want to use a helper function like to allow such types to be inferred for you instead of manually annotated:

```
// helper function
const asDeclarations = <T extends Declarations<T>>(d: T): Declarations<T> => d;

const foo = asDeclarations({ onCollection: 1, foo: "a" });
/* const foo: Declarations<{
    onCollection: number;
    foo: string;
}>*/
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgEwCIQMYBs4Cc7AJYD2AdgM5QC8UA3gLABQUjUxAshALYBGEWAXFEQCuXHgBooAeglQeWAlgCEA4dywCCwKHBIk8AcyJxO6aMAJQSwLHiJ76TZkQDCBdCdT5i-ISKzipMlhyisq+6praugZGJlBmFlY2dgxMANoA1vyW1rYAulmJtvQAvgDc9BV0oJBQKBjYuISkADwAKgB8FNT2aQDSUDZQ6RAgBABmUK35UP0QAB7AEEQIZADkrByqq1AAPlDrzq7unkTbAPyhqlAFOcll9GOCRB5NUKhYELgQbTILSyu1NCYHAnEhtdrtAAUCCBDVB-FaAEpunRipV3p9FpDaClGMQXG40Cd+ABGUQ9PFENi+fgAJnJuKgOGWBHYAHlgAALHitTlJfgAIm5IAFJURpUk0gI6TgIHRHy+2IpjgJxyagoIBDAJAF-mksnk4mySQGZCIGi0On0hmMpnMPlUyo2NKg9KdXJ4vRGguFuuVJFZEC5SXgCFJtIAzHrAsElA6eKbwpaojbYvFjUVUYj0cRLJa6sDGrmuj95otlmQC3CmmCOlCw5NEfwqyCa+CKJ0EOU6Khc5oxpqutoW0XSNiVUcieqoGSoAOCIK4AKoMVxfQJAAqN59uea5uw1u55o4hz4ycvLyXHjdhzzm5JbvFdobiRAA)

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible to do, [in the TypeScript Deep Dive book](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html#excluding-certain-properties-from-the-index-signature) there's a section on exactly this. Although you can declare a type you can't actually create an object with it in TS:

```
// No error on this type declaration:
type Declarations = {
    [key: string]: string;
} & {
    onMember: number;
    onCollection: number;
}

// Error does appear here indicating type `number` is not assignable to type `string`.
const declarations: Declarations = {
    onMember: 0,
    onCollection: 0,
    other: 'Is a string'
}
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEDkHtQUwJzpOpIDtQBcAWBLAzpgJ4AOMoAJjAMYA2AhnHRjmgFwBQGJZAItfY2ZoCAXlABvdqGmgA2gGsYhVqDwY4OVAHMAuirUbtAbnYBfUADIJUmWgCyMALYAjeCtQBXF-BMyUqAGFIGhpqIVR3L1c4E1N2dhBQAFEEJApIGAI6YlIGUCx4Mk1yHComTS0iUlAAA09vOBrQfFBUSAxQOjw8HC1UOmdQzGguapqDCpqAOnYqYQ7KWgZy4RU+JcEWVFFrP3snaJUABgAaG2k0IJCwreOzvew3UAByAEks1XUK57N2IA).