# Give unknown properties in an interface one type; give one known property a conflicting type

Tags: typescript

I am creating an interface for an object representing an XML element. My first go at the interface looked like this:

```
interface Mutation {
  [attribute: string]: string;
  children: Mutation[];
}
```

But when compiling this, TypeScript errored, telling me that the type `Mutation[]` conflicts with the type `string`. So, I thought to exclude the "children" property from `[attribute: string]: string`:

```
interface Mutation {
  [attribute: Exclude<string, "children">]: string;
  children: Mutation[];
}
```

However, this errored again: *An index signature parameter type cannot be a type alias. Consider writing `[attribute: string]: string | Mutation[]` instead.* Counter to the goal, of course!

It is not too difficult to just allow the `Mutation[]` type in `[attribute: string]`, ala `[attribute: string]: Mutation[] | string`. But this means whenever I access a property (besides "children") on a `Mutation`, I need to make explicit that the value will be a string - and TypeScript will not error if I were to set a property besides "children" to an array of `Mutation`s!

**Is there any way to make sure all (unknown) properties in an interface to be one type, while making an exception for a particular (known) property?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicitly typing an object with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612309/explicitly-typing-an-object-with-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, Typescript doesn't like that because the type for `children` doesn't match the generic index type of `string`.  To get around that, split the definition and use a union type to bring both field types together.

```
type Mutation = { children?: Mutation[] } | { [attribute: string]: string };
const test: Mutation = {
  asdf: "adsf",
  children: [{
    qwerty: "qwerty"
  }]
};
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach but it doesn't prevent `{children: "someString"}`.  Nor does a union capture the intent of a "rest index signature" as suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).

Comment: Good point, I forgot to test the `children: string` case.  I guess the solution for this depends on what the problem really is. I can see in some cases, where the shape of the object is truly unknown, children could be a `string | Mutation[]` type otherwise there should be a sub-set of "known" keys that are all of type string.